# How to pass parameters from Servlet via Bean to JSP page with the help of Session?

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets, javabeans

As mentioned below I have made changes to the code which looks like following example, but it doesn't show firstname and lastname in JSP:

Servlet code:

```
//....
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
Person person = (Person) session.getAttribute("person");
if (person == null) {
    person = new Person();                      
}
person.setNewId(newId);
person.setFirstName(firstName);
person.setLastName(lastName);
session.setAttribute("person", person);

RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("jsp Address");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

Person Bean code:

```
private int newId;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;

// Default Constructor
public Person() {}

public Person(int newId, String firstName, String lastName) {
    setNewId(newId);
    setFirstName(firstName);
    setLastName(lastName);
}

//Getter and Setter Methods
public int getNewId() {return newId;}
public void setNewId(int newID) {this.newId = newID;}
public String getFirstName() {return firstName;}
public void setFirstName(String FirstName) {this.firstName = FirstName;}
public String getLastName() {return lastName;}
public void setLastName(String LastName) {this.lastName = LastName;}
```

And in JSP code:

```
<jsp:useBean id="person" type="app.models.Person" scope="session">
    <jsp:getProperty name="person" property="firstName" />
    <jsp:getProperty name="person" property="lastName" />
</jsp:useBean>
```

Output of this JSP page: none

Expected output: firstName lastName

Questions:

```
1. How can i pass parameters from Servlets to JSP via Bean with help of Session? 
2. Is there a better way to do this code? I am using MVC architecture.
```

Comment: How are you accessing the jsp ? -- Also, there is no empty constructor in your Person class 
EDIT: Just saw your response about the empty constructor. Can you clarify how you are accessing the servlet/jsp?

Comment: I am using RequestDispatcher from Servlet to transfer control to named JSP. I have a default constructor. EDIT: I am accessing servlet via DD and JSP through Request Dispatcher.

Comment: After you've deployed this code to your servlet container, you are accessing the servlet first, I hope? Do you get any exceptions in the logs? Have you tried adding some logs before you dispatch request ?

Comment: No! I don't get any exceptions. But my JSP doesn't catch the parameters that I am passing through JSP >>Servlet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the `<jsp:useBean>`. When using the `type` attribute instead of `class`, it won't check if there's already an instance in the scope, it will plain override the `Person` instance which you created in the servlet with a new, blank, default constructed instance.

When using "MVC architecture", the `<jsp:useBean>` tag is useless. Remove it and just use usual [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) to access it:

```
${person.firstName} ${person.lastName}
```

Or better, to prevent [XSS attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting), use [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) `<c:out>`.

```
<c:out value="${person.firstName} ${person.lastName}" />
```

Comment: I suggested the `class` but that didn't work either. Wonder why.

Comment: @CoolBeans: Ah well, then it's either not properly rebuilt or he is running the JSP the wrong way (by calling the JSP URL directly instead of the servlet URL).

Comment: I just used Expression Language instead of     <jsp:useBean>    and its working. Thank you.