# <jsp:useBean> errors with "cannot find symbol" during JSP compile

Tags: jsp, servlets, javabeans

I'm new to Java-EE (starting today). I'm reading a book and doing example simultaneously. At first I wrote a very simple program that takes users information (in index.jsp) via a form, and then shows them in output.jsp.
Then I tried to convert it to MVC-based architecture, using Beans as the Model. So, user's data first goes to a servlet called ControllerServlet.java, data is SET in the Bean, and in the view (output.jsp) data is GET from the bean. But it gives me errors, regarding incorrect use of Beans.

Here is my code:

index.jsp

```
    <%-- 
    Document   : index
    Created on : Dec 8, 2012, 4:16:48 PM
    Author     : mohsen
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Developer survey</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome to SHIT</h1>
        <p>Please indicate shit, so we could be able to do further shit later.</p>
        <form action="output.jsp">
            <table border="0">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Full Name:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="fullName" value="" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Java</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="progLang" value="Java" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Groovy</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="progLang" value="Groovy" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Scala</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="progLang" value="Scala" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>C#</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="progLang" value="C#" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Ruby</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="progLang" value="Ruby" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is SurveyData.java (the Bean)

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

import java.beans.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 *
 * @author mohsen
 */
public class SurveyData implements Serializable {

    public static final String PROP_SAMPLE_PROPERTY = "sampleProperty";
    private String fullName;
    private String[] progLang;
    private PropertyChangeSupport propertySupport;

    public SurveyData() {
        propertySupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public String[] getProgLang() {
        return progLang;
    }

    public void setProgLang(String[] value) {
        String[] oldValue = progLang;
        progLang = value;
        propertySupport.firePropertyChange(PROP_SAMPLE_PROPERTY, oldValue, progLang);
    }

    public void setFullName(String value) {
        String oldValue = fullName;
        fullName = value;
        propertySupport.firePropertyChange(PROP_SAMPLE_PROPERTY, oldValue, fullName);
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        propertySupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        propertySupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }
}
```

Here is ControllerServlet.java:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 *
 * @author mohsen
 */
@WebServlet(name = "ControllerServlet", urlPatterns = {"/ControllerServlet"})
public class ControllerServlet extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP
     * <code>GET</code> and
     * <code>POST</code> methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        SurveyData surveyData = new SurveyData();
        surveyData.setFullName(request.getParameter("fullName"));
        surveyData.setProgLang(request.getParameterValues("progLang"));
        request.setAttribute("surveyData", surveyData);

        request.getRequestDispatcher("output.jsp").forward(request, response);

    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP
     * <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP
     * <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>
}
```

And finally, here is output.js:

```
<%-- 
    Document   : output
    Created on : Dec 8, 2012, 4:42:59 PM
    Author     : mohsen
--%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<jsp:useBean id="surveyData" scope="request" class="SurveyData" />
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Thanks for doing the shit we asked you!</h1>
        <P>
            <%--=request.getParameter("fullName")--%>,
            <jsp:getProperty name="surveyData" property="fullName" />
            you have said that you know these shit:
        </P>
        <ul>
            <% 
                //String[] selectedLanguages = request.getParameterValues("progLang");
                String[] selectedLanguages = surveyData.getProgLang();
                if (selectedLanguages != null){
                    for(int i = 0; i < selectedLanguages.length; i++){
                        %>
                        <li>
                            <%= selectedLanguages[i]%>
                        </li>
                        <%
                    }
                }
            %>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

And these are output errors:

```
Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\mohsen\Documents\NetBeansProjects\simplewebapp\build\generated\classes
C:\Users\mohsen\Documents\NetBeansProjects\simplewebapp\build\generated\src\org\apache\jsp\output_jsp.java:47: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class SurveyData
location: class org.apache.jsp.output_jsp
      SurveyData surveyData = null;
      ^
C:\Users\mohsen\Documents\NetBeansProjects\simplewebapp\build\generated\src\org\apache\jsp\output_jsp.java:49: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class SurveyData
location: class org.apache.jsp.output_jsp
        surveyData = (SurveyData) _jspx_page_context.getAttribute("surveyData", PageContext.REQUEST_SCOPE);
C:\Users\mohsen\Documents\NetBeansProjects\simplewebapp\build\generated\src\org\apache\jsp\output_jsp.java:51: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class SurveyData
location: class org.apache.jsp.output_jsp
          surveyData = new SurveyData();
C:\Users\mohsen\Documents\NetBeansProjects\simplewebapp\build\generated\src\org\apache\jsp\output_jsp.java:67: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class SurveyData
location: class org.apache.jsp.output_jsp
      out.write(org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.toString((((SurveyData)_jspx_page_context.findAttribute("surveyData")).getFullName())));
                                                                        ^
4 errors
C:\Users\mohsen\Documents\NetBeansProjects\simplewebapp\nbproject\build-impl.xml:930: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\mohsen\Documents\NetBeansProjects\simplewebapp\nbproject\build-impl.xml:284: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

By the way I'm using NetBeans.
It seems long, but honestly it just some basic noobie code. I guess my problem is that I don't know Beans very well yet.
Thank you very much

Comment: This is a polite site: Please remove "colourful" language from your code. Thank you.

Comment: You're being too thin skinned in my view, Bohemian.  That's the least of mohsen ny's problems.

Answer (score 1):

Classes in the default package are invisible to classes which are by itself inside a package.

Experiment with it yourself:

```
// No package!

public class Foo {
}
```

```java
package com.example;

public class Bar {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo(); // compile fail, cannot find symbol
    }
}
```

It's exactly the same problem as `<jsp:useBean>` is struggling with under the covers. Put all your public classes in a package if you want them to be visible (and thus be importable) to outside.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, you don't need `<jsp:useBean>` in this construct at all. You've already created and set the bean using a servlet. Get rid of `<jsp:useBean>` tag altogether. Also please make sure that you're reading the proper tutorials. The `<jsp:useBean>` is only to be used in controller-less (read: servlet-less) MVC approach. See also [How to pass parameters from Servlet via Bean to JSP page with the help of Session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798057/how-to-pass-parameters-from-servlet-via-bean-to-jsp-page-with-the-help-of-sessio/5799033#5799033) and [Our servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info).